# How to wait till all components are loaded in Cypress?

Tags: automation, cypress

My Cypress test cases are working fine when I run from my system pointing to QA. But the scheduled builds from CI are failing randomly because sometimes the page is taking more time to load.

I've tried cy.wait(1500) -> It works sometimes and fails sometimes. So, I was wondering is there a command in cypress that waits till all components in the page is loaded. Instead of I try different values inside cy.wait() which in turn fails someday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Cypress has smart waits for all elements to load and the page to render. This section confirms that: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Cypress-is-Not-Like-jQuery

Instead of inserting cy.wait() in each and every step (Best practice is to minimise the use of this), you can include a maximum timeout on your `cypress.json` file:

```
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 30000,
  "pageLoadTimeout": 60000,
  "requestTimeout": 60000,
```

If it still fails, then something is wrong with your test environment and might be a good time for a dev to check its performance as you don't want an environment that loads that long especially if it is a replica of production / live site.

Comment: I have two cypress. json files. One directly under project and one cypress/cypress.json. Which one should I place this code?

Comment: By default, it should be on the root directory (e.g. under project). Also, best way to find out is temporarily remove the one under project, and if your cypress runner does not work, then it means it is the right file :)